# Navigation bar shifts up in the landscape mode - iOS

Tags: ios, landscape-portrait

Portrait

[image]

Landscape

[image]

The navigation bar on iPhone landscape mode shifts up by half the height size whereas on the portrait mode, it looks fine.

Please help.

Comment: Could you add some screenshots (or links to images if your rep is too low) please?

Comment: Potrait and landscape screenshots are attached.

Comment: It is natural behavior of navigation bar that it got smaller in landscape mode. Show your code hows you add your log out button !

Comment: you need o tell us more about the structure of your project, is that a UISplitController with UINavigationVC in the master view or is that Is that bar a  uitoolbar?

Comment: Yes, it is a UISplitController with UINavigationVC in the master view.

Answer (score 0):

In your `viewDidload` you should set logout button and title something like,

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Log out" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;

self.title = @"PROFILE";
```

And it will work fine in both mode portrait and landscape!

**Outputs :**

Portrait

[image]

Landscape

[image]

Comment: My code is the same as what you have posted. I get the same issue.

Comment: barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Log Out", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(AccountsViewController.logOutAction(_:)))
        
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
        
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.en_plusColor()
        
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.en_Logout()], forState: UIControlState.Normal)